# Passing form input states to a directive template in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Given this form

```
<form class="form-signin" name="registerForm" role="registration" ng-submit="submit(registerForm)" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group username has-feedback">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="registerObj.name" minlength="4" maxlength="32" required ng-model-options="{debounce : {'default' : 500, blur : 0}}">
    <span class="form-control-feedback" ng-if="registerForm.$submitted || registerForm.name.$touched">
      <i ng-if="registerForm.name.$pending" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin-short"></i>
      <span ng-if="registerForm.name.$pending" class="sr-only">(validating)</span>
      <span ng-if="registerForm.name.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span ng-if="registerForm.name.$invalid" class="sr-only">(error)</span>
      <span ng-if="registerForm.name.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span ng-if="registerForm.name.$valid" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Is it possible to make everything under the input element a template so I can re-use it for other inputs in this form or in any other form with something like:

```
 <input-feedback aform="registerForm" aname="name"></input-feedback>
```

I'm learning Angular and until now I managed to do everything I want, but this got me stuck. I'm not able to pass all those states (registerForm.name.$valid, etc) to a directive so they do what I'd want them to do.

The idea is to be able to have a form like:

```
<form class="form-signin" name="registerForm" role="registration" ng-submit="submit(registerForm)" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group username has-feedback">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="registerObj.name" minlength="4" maxlength="32" required ng-model-options="{debounce : {'default' : 500, blur : 0}}">
    <input-feedback aform="registerForm" aname="name"></input-feedback>

    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="registerObj.email" maxlength="32" required ng-model-options="{debounce : {'default' : 500, blur : 0}}">
    <input-feedback aform="registerForm" aname="email"></input-feedback>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also to be able to use the directive in other form that don't have the name "registerForm", and with different fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zuDfSdU1pkibcBOUC3cL?p=preview

Here's the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('inputFeedback', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    template:    '<span class="form-control-feedback" ng-if="registerForm.$submitted || registerForm.name.$touched">' +
      '<i ng-if="registerForm.name.$pending" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin-short"></i>' +
      '<span ng-if="registerForm.name.$pending" class="sr-only">(validating)</span>' +
      '<span ng-if="registerForm.name.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
      '<span ng-if="registerForm.name.$invalid" class="sr-only">(error)</span>' +
      '<span ng-if="registerForm.name.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
      '<span ng-if="registerForm.name.$valid" class="sr-only">(success)</span>' +
    '</span>'
  }
});
```

Note the use of scope false... Although that may not be 'good design' what you're essentially asking for is to dump a blob of HTML somewhere, not to have self contained behaviors. scope: false is arguably more transparent.

Comment: That won't do it. The point was to make that directive reusable. Meaning I can add a second field in the same form and use the directive instead of writing the whole thing with changing the name of the field.

I also want to be able to use it other forms.